# Mazda parts staff substituted Mazda ATF for Ford ATF ... Safe?

Tags: atf

I am due for ATF change on Mazda CX-9 GT 2008. I went to a Mazda dealership parts department to ask for the ATF. The worker come back with 6 bottles of: "Ford Motocraft Premium Automatic Transmission fluid". On the back it says:

- Recommended for use in the F21 6-speed transmission
- Meets Ford Specification WSS-M3C924-A
- Do not use for applications where MERCON, MERCON V. MERCON SP or Type F fluids are recommended.

Now the service manual states:

- ATF type: JWS3309

The Mazda tech said (something like) "This is good for all 6 speed transmissions from the Mazda 6 from about 2004 onwards" (it may have been 2006)

Now I am perplexed. An official Mazda provided gives me Ford ATF which appears to be different. I am told it will be fine, but I have my doubts. I cannot really find anything solid to convince me one way or the other.

As a side point it does make me wonder what ATF Mazda puts in when you get the service done from them.

Is there any information anywhere to prove that this is okay to use, or conversely that I should not use at all?

Comment: I don't know *for sure*, but considering Ford owns part of Mazda and they share a lot of the same platforms, I'd suggest the ATF's are most likely interchangeable.

Comment: Been a few weeks seems to run fine so guess so, interesting